Always get wrong value on onClick event
I create a Table to display some values
const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<readonly number[]>([]);
const isSelected = (id: number) => selected.indexOf(id) !== -1;

return (
<TableContainer>
             <Table sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
               {listVersions
                 ? listVersions.map((current_version, index) => {
                     const isItemSelected = isSelected(index+ 1);
                     const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;
                     return (
                       <TableRow
                         hover
                         onClick={() => handleClick(index + 1, current_version, isItemSelected)}
                         role="checkbox"
                         aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                         tabIndex={-1}
                         key={index + 1}                         
                         selected={isItemSelected}
                         sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                       >
                         <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                           <Checkbox
                             color="primary"
                             checked={isItemSelected}
                             inputProps={{
                               "aria-labelledby": labelId,
                             }}
                           />
                         </TableCell>
                         <TableCell>{current_version}</TableCell>
                       </TableRow>
...
);

I need to get selected current_version.
So handleClick looks like :
const handleClick = (id: number, version: string, isItemSelected: boolean) => {
  console.log(version , isItemSelected); // Here, isItemSelected get wrong value, if I select row, I get false, expected value is true
 const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(id);
    let newSelected: readonly number[] = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, id);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1),
      );
    }
    setSelected(newSelected);
} 

Right version is displayed into console, but Its state, selected or not, is always the inversed value. When I select the row, value is false, when I deselect row, value is true.
Expected value is true when row is selected.
I don't inderstand what is wrong

If I understand react correctly then the whole point is to only respond and change what is necessary, Since in your scope your isSelected is set at first render, the handler for the click won't change it's scope and always see that initial value? Isn't this what you guys should use hooks for to get the current value?

which hook I need to use ?

One that's used to keep track of variables changing. Usually it's something like const [ val, setVal ] = someHook( initialValue ). Don't know for sure, not a react fan or user, was hoping someone with more react knowledge could clarify. But since you don't really know about the hook I'm betting thats what's happening here, you are just logging the const and it's value never changes in the scope of your handler.

I used useState before, but if I deselect row, value from row is still into state array

React state updates are not synchronous, and there are a million questions about this. Also anytime you are using a previous value you should really use the form of the argument to the hook setter for that: setSelected((currentSelected) => { /* logic goes here */ });. The logic in your isSelected function is probably wrong, but you don't show it so who knows.

@JaredSmith Passing a function to setState is really only necessary if you are setting the same state multiple times before the next render or if inside a closure with a stale value (especially useEffect). If just setting the state once, there is no problem with relying on the current state to create the next state.

I update my post with isSelected fn

There's still no isSelected in the code above as far as I can see?

isSelected is defined in line 2

   const isSelected = (id: number) => selected.indexOf(id) !== -1; ```

Finally, I successfullly fix my issue, I deal with table index
